# Change value of a cloned object

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an object that has an instance variable array called `my_array`. I declare it via `attr_accessor`.

```
my_object.my_array = [1,2,3] # <= I don't know the max size of my_array(it can be dynamic)
```

I want to create the same object with `my_object` and fill its `my_array` with only one element. The value inside that element is each value from `my_array`'s element (from `my_object`). Because the size of `my_array` is dynamic I suppose I need to iterate it via `each`.

Here's my attempt:

```
my_object.my_array.each do |element|          # <= my_object is a special object
  new_object = nil unless new_object.nil?
  new_object = my_object.clone # <= I create new object with same class with my_object
  new_object.my_array.clear   # <= clear all element inside it.
  new_object.my_array.push(element)  # assign element value to the first element.
  # rest of code #
  new_object = nil 
end
```

The iteration is not iterating properly. The size of `my_object.my_array` is 3, then it should iterating three times, but it's not, it's only iterating one time. I believe it's because of `new_object.my_array.clear`, but I cloned it from `my_object`, so why this happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that `clone` will make a shallow clone, not a deep clone. In other words, `my_array` is a reference and the cloned instance references the same array in memory. Consider:

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :my_array
end

a = MyClass.new
a.my_array = [1, 2, 3]
a.my_array
#=> [1, 2, 3]

b = a.clone
b.my_array.push(4)
b.my_array
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
a.my_array              # also changed!
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

In order to fix this, you need to extend the `initialize_copy` method to also clone the array:

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :my_array

  def initialize_copy(orig)
    super
    self.my_array = orig.my_array.clone
  end
end

a = MyClass.new
a.my_array = [1, 2, 3]
a.my_array
#=> [1, 2, 3]

b = a.clone
b.my_array.push(4)
b.my_array
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
a.my_array              # did not change, works as expected
#=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you assign one array it just copies the reference and both of them point to the same reference,
so a change in one is reflected when you print either of them:

```
orig_array = [1,2,3,4]<br>
another_array = orig_array

puts orig_array.unshift(0).inspect
puts another_array.inspect
```

Which outputs:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

To avoid this you can use Marshal to copy from the original array without impacting the object to which it is copied.
Any changes in the original array will not change the object to which it is copied.

```
orig_array = [1,2,3,4]
another_array = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(orig_array))

puts orig_array.unshift(0).inspect
puts another_array.inspect
```

Which outputs:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```